# UINavigationController shows blank view

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, iphone

I am making a simple navigation based application that drills down one level and show a new xib file each time. When I drill down one level my screen shows up blank. I still have the navigation controller at the top with a back button but my view dosent load.

Here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    circle_area *subViewOneController = [[circle_area alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tvc = subViewOneController;
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

like I said this returns a blank screen.

My updated Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
circle_area *subViewOneController = [[circle_area alloc] init];
UIViewController *tvc = subViewOneController;
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"section %i special button!", indexPath.section);
                NSLog(@"row %i special button!", indexPath.row);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
NSLog(@"section %i!", indexPath.section);
NSLog(@"row %i!", indexPath.row);
NSLog(tvc.view.recursiveDescription);
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:subViewOneController animated:YES];
}
[tvc release];
}
```

Last time i left out the switches in the middle, it dosent look like they would effect anything , but i included them this time.

Comment: Maybe you should post the init code of your circle_area class...

Answer (score 2):

```
circle_area *subViewOneController = [[circle_area alloc] init];
```

In this line, you are creating an instance of the `circle_area` class and assigning it to the pointer called `subViewOneController`.

```
UIViewController *tvc = subViewOneController;
```

In this line, you are assigning that same instance to a pointer called `tvc`.  This pointer is defined to point to an instance of the `UIViewController` class.

It's not clear what you are trying to do here.  What is `circle_area`?  Why the redundant assignment?  Is `circle_area` a subclass of `UIViewController`?  If it isn't, then that's the problem and you should have been warned about it by the compiler.

In addition, you have a memory leak.  You allocate memory for this `circle_area` instance, but you don't release it.

Comment: circle_area is the name of the view I am trying to switch to (circle_area.m circle_area.h circle_area.xib)

Comment: The name of the view or the name of the view controller?

Comment: Thought i would mention that i plugged the leak and removed the line: 'UIViewController *tvc = subViewOneController;' Still same result. @jim the name of the view controller

Comment: Check that your nib is being copied into your app bundle.  Right-click it, select `Get Info` and look to see if your target is checked.  Also, `NSLog(tvc.view.recursiveDescription);` could highlight some problems.

Comment: I will repost my updated code so that you can see what it looks like now but `NSLog(tvc.view.recursiveDescription);` returns an error in the compiler. the error is "request for member 'recursiveDescription' in something not a structure or union"

 I also checked and the target **is** checked.

Comment: Apologies, wasn't paying attention.  I meant `NSLog(@"%@", [tvc.view recursiveDescription]);`

Comment: When I run the console shows `<UIView: 0x4b41020; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b3a940>>`

Comment: Okay, that's saying that you've got a single `UIView` with nothing in it.  I'm assuming you expect there to be more in there?  What's in your nib?  Have you overridden `loadView`?

Comment: currently in my nib there are 3 text boxes and nothing else. I have never had to override `loadview`. How would I do that?

Comment: well this is strange... I opened my nib in IB again to check. Out of pure curiosity I saved again (even though no changes were made) and now it runs properly.